# How do you calculate the area of the intersection between a rectangle and a doughnut?

Tags: geometry, circles, area, rectangles

I'm dealing with an engineering problem, involving concentric pipes, with air flowing through the outer pipe (doughnut).
I need a cross-beam to support the inner pipe, so I need to calculate how much of the outer doughnut's area will be consumed by the cross beam, in order to determine aerodynamic impact on the airflow through the outer circle of the doughnut.

The picture below illustrates what I'm trying to do.
I need to calculate the area of the gold section.

The actual height of the blue rectangle is irrelevant - it crosses both circles exactly twice, it is perpendicular to the axes, and it is centered over the vertical axis.

The intersection is fully rounded on both ends, exactly meeting the edges of both circles.

[image]

Comment: Is the intersection supposed to have rounded ends (meeting the two circles exactly), or is it a rectangle that's tangent to the inner circle and meeting the outer circle at the two outer corners? If it's the former, I'm pretty sure we have to integrate; if it's the latter, things get a lot simpler.

Comment: @DylanSp Both ends of the intersection are rounded to meet both circles exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, let's think together.

- First, I will calculate the area of the intersection between the rectangle and the upper half of the big circle with radius $R$, assuming the rectangle goes from the center of the circle and up. As shown:

[image]

- The resulting area would be the sum of:

  1. a sector with angle $\theta = 2 \tan^{-1} (\frac{w}{2R})$ and, hence, area of $\frac{\theta}{2 \pi} \pi R^2$
  2. one small triangle on the left with area $\frac{1}{2}(\frac{w}{2}) (R \cos(\frac{\theta}{2}))$
  3. one small triangle on the right with area $\frac{1}{2}(\frac{w}{2}) (R \cos(\frac{\theta}{2}))$
- Finally, your area can be calculated by subtraction as follows:
  $$
  A = \frac{\theta_1 R^2}{2} + \frac{w R}{2} \cos(\frac{\theta_1}{2}) - \frac{\theta_2 r^2}{2} - \frac{w r}{2} \cos(\frac{\theta_2}{2}).
  $$

where $\theta_1 = 2 \tan^{-1} (\frac{w}{2R})$ and $ \theta_2=2 \tan^{-1} (\frac{w}{2r})$.

Comment: Can you describe the sector and two triangles you're using to find the area of intersection? I'm not seeing it.

Comment: I have updated the answer

Comment: I'm not sure that this works as written; $\theta$ for the small circle is different than $\theta$ for the large circle. It's a good approach, but work through the calculation of $A_R$ for the large circle, $A_r$ for the smaller circle, and find $A = A_R - A_r$.

Comment: you are right! I have addressed this point in the edited answer

Comment: That should do the trick. @giffyguy, Hamid's answer is probably better than mine, it's certainly much cleaner.

Comment: @DylanSp Thanks for reviewing it! Yeah, if I can avoid integration, that would be very helpful. Let's keep the calculus answer around as well, of course, since it could also be helpful and informative for future visitors.

Answer (score 3):

The equations for the upper semicircles of the small pipe and large pipe are $f(x) = \sqrt{r^2 - x^2}$ and $g(x) = \sqrt{R^2 - x^2}$ respectively. The area of the cross-beam is then found by integrating $g(x) - f(x)$ over the interval $[-\frac{w}{2}, \frac{w}{2}]$:
\begin{align*}
\int_{-w/2}^{w/2} (g(x) - f(x))\,dx &= \int_{-w/2}^{w/2} g(x)\,dx - \int_{-w/2}^{w/2} f(x)\,dx \\
&= \int_{-w/2}^{w/2} \sqrt{R^2 - x^2}\,dx - \int_{-w/2}^{w/2} \sqrt{r^2 - x^2}\,dx \\
&= \left[\frac{1}{2} x \sqrt{R^2-x^2} 
+\frac{1}{2}R^2\arctan\frac{x}{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}\right]^{w/2}_{-w/2} - \left[\frac{1}{2} x \sqrt{r^2-x^2} 
+\frac{1}{2}r^2\arctan\frac{x}{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}\right]^{w/2}_{-w/2} \tag 1
\end{align*}
I should note that this is somewhat incomplete; I don't know if it's possible to simplify this expression before calculating it. That said, it should be possible to calculate it from this point.

David Quinn pointed out that $\arctan\frac{x}{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}=\arcsin\frac xR$ (which follows from the definitions of $\sin$ and $\tan$). Using this, we can simplify equation $(1)$ as
\begin{align*}
\left[\frac{1}{2} x \sqrt{R^2-x^2} 
+\frac{1}{2}R^2\arctan\frac{x}{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}\right]^{w/2}_{-w/2} - \left[\frac{1}{2} x \sqrt{r^2-x^2} 
+\frac{1}{2}r^2\arctan\frac{x}{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}\right]^{w/2}_{-w/2} &= \left[\frac{1}{2} x \sqrt{R^2-x^2} 
+\frac{1}{2}R^2\arcsin\frac{x}{r}\right]^{w/2}_{-w/2} - \left[\frac{1}{2} x \sqrt{r^2-x^2} 
+\frac{1}{2}r^2\arcsin\frac{x}{r}\right]^{w/2}_{-w/2} \tag 2
\end{align*}

Evaluating each part of $(2)$ for $x = -\frac{w}{2}$ to $x = \frac{w}{2}$, we have [INCOMPLETE]
\begin{align*}
\left[\frac{1}{2} x \sqrt{R^2-x^2} 
+\frac{1}{2}R^2\arcsin\frac{x}{r}\right]^{w/2}_{-w/2} - \left[\frac{1}{2} x \sqrt{r^2-x^2} 
+\frac{1}{2}r^2\arcsin\frac{x}{r}\right]^{w/2}_{-w/2} &= 
\frac{w}{2}\sqrt{R^2 - x^2} - \frac{w}{2}\sqrt{r^2 - x^2} (+ \ldots)
\end{align*}

Comment: What do you think of Hamid's answer? Is that a simplified version of what you provided?

Comment: @Giffyguy I'm honestly not sure, sorry.

Comment: Note that $\arctan\frac{x}{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}=\arcsin\frac xR$

Comment: I started working it further with David Quinn's suggestion, though it's somewhat messy and complex. I'll get back to this tomorrow if/when I have time to work it out and clean up the notation.